# Is there a collection for storing discrete intervals?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I need to store discrete ranges in a set, joining adjacent ranges upon insertion. Is there a structure in STL which already has such functionality?

I have tried boost::intervals, but it's quite heavy and a bit of an overkill for what I'm trying to do.

For example, assume the set is empty and the the following elements are inserted:

```
[64, 96]
[0, 4]
[11, 15]
[5, 10]
```

The expected contents of the interval set should be as follows:

```
[0, 15]
[64, 96]
```

Comment: There's no ready container that will handle it all for you. For the container itself you could perhaps use a [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) of [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair). But for the merging of ranges you have to handle it yourself.

Comment: I like [DIET trees](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/diet/) for this, but I don't think I've ever seen a C++ implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well known question. There is a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) on possible solutions to your question. Of course in the C++ STL you could implement a solution based on the Naive approach, explained in wikipedia, using a `std::map` because a map is a Red-Black Tree which is a type of Binary Search Tree.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you want to merge intervals in case they are adjacent to each other makes your task much easy than proposed *interval tree* approach.

Instead you can use data structures proposed by `Some programmer dude` and roll out your own implementation very quickly. Here i provide a possible implementation:

```
class IntervalSet {
    std::map<int, int> _intervals;

public:
    void Add(int smaller, int bigger) {
        const auto next = _intervals.upper_bound(smaller);
        if (next != _intervals.cbegin()) {
            const auto prev = std::prev(next);
            if (next != _intervals.cend() && next->first <= bigger + 1) {
                bigger = next->second;
                _intervals.erase(next);
            }
            if (prev->second + 1 >= smaller) {
                smaller = prev->first;
                _intervals.erase(prev);
            }
        }
        _intervals[smaller] = bigger;
    }

    const auto& Intervals() const { return _intervals; }

    bool IsInsideInterval(int v) const {
        const auto suspectNext = _intervals.upper_bound(v);
        const auto suspect = std::prev(suspectNext);
        return suspect->first <= v && v <= suspect->second;
    }
};
```

Small tests:

```
IntervalSet is;
is.Add(64, 96);
is.Add(0, 4);
is.Add(11, 15);
is.Add(5, 10);
for (const auto p : is.Intervals()) std::cout << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ") ";
```

> (0, 15) (64, 96)

It works with intersecting intervals as well:

```
IntervalSet is;
is.Add(0, 10);
is.Add(5, 15);
is.Add(10, 20);
for (const auto p : is.Intervals()) std::cout << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ") ";
```

> (0,20)

Comment: What about `is.Add(64, 96); is.Add(11, 15); is.Add(5, 9); is.Add(0, 128);`? Feels like a loop is missing